# Where should I put deviceready on multipage PhoneGap App?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, cordova

1) I have multiple pages PhoneGap applications. Each of them may call PhoneGap API.
Should I put `deviceready` listener on every pages, or is it sufficient to put on the first page only?

2) I use AngularJS routing with `<ng-view>` to enable single page application. The main page is `index.html`, all the other pages are just embedded on `<ng-view>`inside index.html. Each of those pages may call PhoneGap API. Is it sufficient to put deviceready listener on index.html only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add device ready in index.html as in angualrjs all other pages are going to be included in index.html by ng-view. deviceready should work fine this way.

Also bootstrap your angularjs after deviceready called as it can cause issues if you are going to use your app offline.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I made it works by putting device ready in index.html, and bootstrap angularjs in deviceready callback. However it is not optimized since it blocks the UI rendering until the connection to PhoneGap native process is established.

Better approach is described [here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-on-mobile.html). Basically he uses promise pattern, so that only Phonegap API call waits for the deviceready event. The UI rendering and angularjs bindings could be done even before deviceready is called. This way, the user experience would be better.

```
angular.module('fsCordova', [])
.service('CordovaService', ['$document', '$q',
  function($document, $q) {

    var d = $q.defer(),
        resolved = false;

    var self = this;
    this.ready = d.promise;

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      resolved = true;
      d.resolve(window.cordova);
    });

    // Check to make sure we didn't miss the 
    // event (just in case)
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!resolved) {
        if (window.cordova) d.resolve(window.cordova);
      }
    }, 3000);
}]);

angular.module('myApp', ['fsCordova'])
.controller('MyController', 
  function($scope, CordovaService) {
    CordovaService.ready.then(function() {
      // Cordova is ready
    });
});
```